# What AWS instances are most efficient to run python code on?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, python

I hope this is the right stack for this kind of question.

I am facing a large task with python that needs to be processed. Running it on my machine would take around 60 hours. This task is run by the cpu, not gpu.

The `c5` instances seem to be made for cpu heavy tasks so my first instance was a `c5.4xlarge` windows instance. After getting the python script running on the instance, I was astonished how slow it was. It took about the same time my Laptop takes per task batch. I terminated it and tried a `m5.4xlarge` instance with the same result.

What am I doing wrong? These instances should run 10 times faster than my Laptop with its `i7-8550U` CPU.

Comment: Why do you need Windows to run a Python script? Bottleneck might be disk io. You could check if you get a better performance with io1 disk. You should setup monitoring to figure out the bottleneck. I the script able to utilize multiple threads?

Comment: I don't know which site is most appropriate for this type of question, but what will be crucial to figure out your problem is understanding the application that you are running. To what extent does your application do parallell processing (does it actually take advantage of the 16 vCPUs of a `c5.4xlarge`)? If it's all single-threaded your laptop may well be faster.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist now that you say it, no I don't think it does take advantage of parallel processing. No wonder it's that slow. It's a simple script to run through folders, read hdf5 files, make some calculations and save the plots.

Comment: Maybe you can run multiple scripts in parallel, partitioning the data? The i3 instances and local disk are probably the answer in AWS. Modern desktop CPUs are about as fast as Xeon cores, and IMHO in real world terms CPU speed doesn't advance all that quickly for many real world workloads - partly because many jobs are I/O bound.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of aspects to consider:

- Can your application make use of **multiple CPU cores**? Larger EC2 instances give you more CPU cores but typically not faster single-core performance. Make sure your application can do **parallel processing** to make use of all the CPU cores available.

  If it can't run parallel processing see if you can maybe split the data into multiple **independent batches** and run multiple copies of the app in parallel, each one utilising a single core.
- Where do you **store your data**? If they are on *EBS volume* it can be quite slow comparing to *instance local storage* (aka *ephemeral storage*). Not all EC2 instances offer instance storage - check the [Amazon EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) table for details. It may pay off to **copy the data to instance storage** before processing to improve the data access performance.

  Another option is to use *Storage optimised instance* with *Provisioned IOPS EBS volume* but that's typically very expensive.
- If your app does a lot of **networking** during the computation make sure you're not throttled on that front either. Choose an EC2 instance that's got high *Networking Performance*.

For experiments like this you may find it useful to use [**Spot Instances**](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) that can save you up to 90% of the running costs (or for the same price can get you a lot bigger instance). However be aware of some trade-offs, mainly the fact that the instance may be terminated at any time if the demand for the particular instance type increases.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading/writing lots of files to disk no wonder script is slower in AWS as io operations there usually rely on network connection (search EBS).

You can try i3 instance type, they offer fast SSD disks. But more correct approach which will save you money and time is to investigate what is the bottleneck in your case: cpu, ram or io and adjust script to overcome it.